# Repeating texture in a Rectangle of a variable size

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a texture that I want to repeat inside a `Rectangle` drawn by `canvas.before`. The problem is that I don't know what is going to be the size of the `Rectangle` (it's used as a background for its widget).

For example, I have a `Rectangle` that has `48` px height and width `100` - `500` px. I want to fill its content by horizontally repeating a `48x48` texture.

I know and tried setting `texture.wrap = 'repeat'` and `texture.uvsize` and it works correctly but only if I know the widget size beforehand. For example, setting `uvsize = (3, 1)` for a widget with size `144x48` works fine.

However, this doesn't work when I want to update `uvsize` before redrawing the widget. I created a canvas callback and updated `uvsize` there but this has no effect for some reason:

```
...
with self.canvas.before:
    self.cb = Callback(self.on_canvas_redraw)

...

def on_canvas_redraw(self, instr):
    self.texture.uvsize = (self.width / 48, 1)
```

So how can I dynamically update `uvsize`? Or is there a better way to handle widget resize or a better way to this altogether?

Comment: Bind a function to your widget's size and use this to set your uvsize.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I tried that and the callback is triggered correctly but changing `uvsize` there doesn't make any difference. It only works when I change `uvsize` inside `__init__`

Comment: Maybe that's a bug, not sure. Try using the tex_coords instead.

Comment: I tried overriding `tex_coords` but it says `AttributeError: attribute 'tex_coords' of 'kivy.graphics.texture.Texture' objects is not writable`. I tried recreating the texture in the binded callback and it works.